# Sharing data contract and objects between .NET WCF and .NETMF using DPWS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-micro-framework

I have been trying to achieve this for a few days.

- I have a WCF service in .NET 4.5
- I have a DPWS client in .NETMF 4.3
- I have a shared library of entities built in .NETMF 4.3 and imported
  into both projects.

My aim is to..

1. create a object in .NET
2. pass it via a WCF call to .NETMF
3. work on said object in .NETMF
4. pass it back to .NET

I generate WSDL from the WCF web service and use MFSvcUtil.exe to create a client code for NETMF.

My problem is that I can't seem to be able to get the generated NETMF client code to use the shared domain entity objects from the library. I have tried using the /C: switch from MFSvcUtil.exe...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd170127.aspx

...to specify the file containing all the entities and thought it would then use those objects. Currently the tool just creates proxy objects. Trying to cast them to domain entities gives an inevitable...

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'CommonCore.Comms.MsgObjects.CommandList' to 'schemas.datacontract.org.CommonCore.Comms.MsgObjects.CommandList'*

Any help on this would be appreciated. It looks like it should be possible.